# Building Python 2.7.1 on Mac OS X, import threading and a KeyError Exception

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, python, compile, threading

**Original Problem:**

I am building Python 2.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.7 and am having issues with a `KeyError` exception being thrown from the `threading` module when Python is quit (likely on the `atexit` call).

I haven't been able to find a proper answer anywhere, and am wondering if someone here knows what the issue may be and how to perhaps compile/configure Python correctly in order to avoid this.

The steps to produce the error is relatively short:

```
echo "import threading" | ./python
```

This produces the following output:

```
Exception KeyError: KeyError(140735086161056,) in <module 'threading' from '/Users/danerik/quantumnotes/qw-control/quantumsource/external-libs/build/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

The error is in all likelihood harmless (I have experienced no ill effects), but the message is undesirable and I would prefer it not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I experienced was that I had a custom Modules/main.c file from an older Python release (2.6.1) polluting my 2.7.1 release. Although nearly identical, the main difference is that in the 2.6.1 main.c file there was a `WaitForThreadShutdown(void)` routine that would perform operations if the threading module had been imported. A new custom `Modules/main.c` file was then made based on the new 2.7.1 release, and this solved my issue.

My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The build of python2.7 from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to doesn't have that problem.  You could just get it from them, or try comparing your configure flags to [theirs](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/python27/Portfile) and see what differs.

Comment: The build from Homebrew also doesn't suffer this... I've been looking at their build flags, and can't seem to find differences in their configure script. Perhaps I'm overlooking something...

Comment: I figured out my problem - it was an issue of a version mismatch in the `Modules/main.c` file. I was mixing 2.6.1 code with 2.7.1 code.

Comment: @Dan Glad to hear it.  I see that you edited your question to include the fix too.  Around here it would be more natural to add the solution as an answer and then mark it "accepted" rather than making it part of the question.

Comment: Alright - I'll do that. Thanks for tip! It'll have to wait a bit - as I'm under 100 in reputation, I can first self-answer in 6 hours :)